# How to make nested element animate on mouseover of parent element

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery, but i am having hard time getting what i want.I want the element wrapped inside my `<div>`and `<li>` to animate or do things which i pass in it. 
While i have gotten some success, but if i have 10 div, all of my title inside 10 div disappear, when mouseover just one. It can be done via `$(this)` but like i said i am new. Following is my code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".products > ul > li").on('mouseenter',function(){
    //slide up h3 or div.cat-title
   $(this).closest(".products")
     .find(".cat-title")
     .fadeIn('slow');
     });
    $(".products > ul > li").on('mouseleave',function(){
    //slide down h3 (and hide)
  $(this).closest(".products")
    .find("h3")
    .fadeOut('slow');
    });

});
```

while my html is

```
<div class="products">
 <ul class="products">
  <li class="product">
   <a href="#">
    <img width="180" height="190" alt="Beauty & Pampering" src="#">
     <h3>
      </a>
      <div class="cat-title">Beauty & Pampering</div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: since all the relevant elements are within the `li` change `$(this).closest(".products")` to `$(this).closest(".product")` and try

Comment: also can you try to recreate the issue in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VZBxd/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny oh great, it worked! is there a simple way to target a nested element and do stuff, when a parent element event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...

$('.products > ul > li').on('mouseenter',function(){
   $(".cat-title", this).fadeIn('slow');
});

...
```

You can trigger events only under this object.

User jQuery `hover()` instead of `on(mouseenter)` and `on(mouseleave)`

```
$('.products > ul > li').hover(function(){
   $(".cat-title", this).fadeIn('slow');
},function(){
   $(".cat-title", this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: yes, that's it! I never knew you can pass .parent as a argument.

Comment: Glad I could help. This is for when you have multiple "parent" classes. http://jsfiddle.net/4u86C/5/

Comment: awesome! if you can make it answer. I would happy to accept it. btw what kind of behavior this is called?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how I can call this, I don't even know if it's called somehow. If you can create a working jsfiddle (with css and etc) with your code from above I could help you exactly. I don't get to much from your posted code.

Comment: [here](jsfiddle.net/FMLHu/5/) i want to hide the black div, and on mouseover on each, show it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .children() ?

Check this example for a demo.

[.children() Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-children-example)

Here is the [Jquery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Try something like

```
$('ul.products').on('mouseenter', function(){

$('div.products').children('ul').css('background','green'); 

});

$('div.products').on('mouseleave', function(){

$('.products').children('div').css('background','yellow'); 

});
```

And here is the JS Fiddle for your understanding - http://jsfiddle.net/Pm2Tj/1/

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, but see at my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4u86C/1/). I dont know how to target inner elements

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".products > ul > li").on('mouseleave', function () {
    //slide down h3 (and hide)
    $(this).closest(".product")
        .find("h3")
        .fadeOut('slow');
});
```